# N1QL query dropping records after join with a subquery

Tags: nosql, couchbase, sql++

The Below Query is dropping records when i join 2 N1QL sub queries -
We are using couchbase and using N1QL queries.

```
Full Query - 
select
t3.appName,
t3.uuid_proj as uuid,
t3.description,
t3.env,
t3.productStatus
from      
               ( select 
                              t1.uuid as uuid_proj ,
                              t1.appName as appName ,
                              t1.description as description,
                              t2.env as env,
                              t2.productStatus as productStatus
                              from 
                                             (
                                             select 
                                             api_external.uuid ,
                                             api_external.data.appName , 
                                             api_external.data.description 
                                             from `api_external` 
                                             where type = 'partnerApp' 
                                             and data.companyId = '70a149da27cc425da86cba890bf5b143' )t1
                              join 
                                             (
                                             select 
                                             api_external.data.env,
                                             api_external.data.productStatus,
                                             api_external.data.partnerAppId
                                             from 
                                             `api_external` 
                                             where type = 'integration' )t2
                              on t1.uuid = t2.partnerAppId 
               ) as t3 

join ( 
                              select t4.uuid as uuid_agg , min(t5.env) as env
                              from
                              (select api_external.uuid   from `api_external` where type = 'partnerApp' and data.companyId = '70a149da27cc425da86cba890bf5b143' )as t4 join
                              (select api_external.data.env, api_external.data.partnerAppId from `api_external` where type = 'integration' ) as t5
                              on t4.uuid = t5.partnerAppId
                              group by t4.uuid 
               ) as t6 
on
t3.uuid_proj = t6.uuid_agg and t3.env = t6.env
```

As you see it has 2 sub queries -
The below subquery gives 16 records -

```
select    
                              t1.uuid as uuid_proj 
                              from 
                                             (
                                             select 
                                             api_external.uuid ,
                                             api_external.data.appName , 
                                             api_external.data.description 
                                             from `api_external` 
                                             where type = 'partnerApp' 
                                             and data.companyId = '70a149da27cc425da86cba890bf5b143' )t1
                              join 
                                             (
                                             select 
                                             api_external.data.env,
                                             api_external.data.productStatus,
                                             api_external.data.partnerAppId
                                             from 
                                             `api_external` 
                                             where type = 'integration' )t2
                              on t1.uuid = t2.partnerAppId
                              group by t1.uuid
```

Also the other subquery also gives 16 records -

```
select t4.uuid as uuid_agg , min(t5.env) as env
                              from
                              (select api_external.uuid   from `api_external` where type = 'partnerApp' and data.companyId = '70a149da27cc425da86cba890bf5b143' )as t4 join
                              (select api_external.data.env, api_external.data.partnerAppId from `api_external` where type = 'integration' ) as t5
                              on t4.uuid = t5.partnerAppId
                              group by t4.uuid
```

By Logic join of both the queries on the same grain UUID must also give 16 records . But it gives only 1 .
What am i doing wrong Please help

Comment: It should work. You should check data  each join result and make sure it matched  t3.uuid_proj = t6.uuid_agg and t3.env = t6.env  . first remove env and see what you get

Comment: This is bug https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-55059. Use t6, t3 as CTE and then join for workaround

Answer (score 0):

The query uses many subqueries and hit the issue.
Try following simplified version

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON api_external(data.companyId, uuid, data.appName, data.description) WHERE type = "partnerApp";
CREATE INDEX ix2 ON api_external(data.partnerAppId, data.env, data.productStatus) WHERE type = "integration";

WITH ct3 AS (SELECT t1.uuid, t1.data.appName, t1.data.description,
                    t2.data.env, t2.data.productStatus
              FROM api_external AS t1
              JOIN api_external AS t2 ON t1.uuid = t2.data.partnerAppId
              WHERE t1.type = "partnerApp"
                    AND t1.data.companyId = "70a149da27cc425da86cba890bf5b143"
                    AND t2.type = "integration"
                    AND t2.data.partnerAppId IS NOT NULL),
    ct6 AS ( SELECT t4.uuid AS uuid_agg , MIN(t5.data.env) AS env
             FROM api_external AS t4
             JOIN api_external AS t5 ON t4.uuid = t5.data.partnerAppId
             WHERE t4.type = "partnerApp"
                   AND t4.data.companyId = "70a149da27cc425da86cba890bf5b143"
                   AND t5.type = "integration"
                   AND t5.data.partnerAppId IS NOT NULL
             GROUP BY t4.uuid)
SELECT t3.*
FROM ct3 AS t3
JOIN ct6 AS t6 ON t3.uuid = t6.uuid_agg and t3.env = t6.env;
```

If same results see following works . After JOIN get all the fields of results of MIN env record each group

```
SELECT m[1].*
FROM api_external AS t4
JOIN api_external AS t5 ON t4.uuid = t5.data.partnerAppId
WHERE t4.type = "partnerApp"
       AND t4.data.companyId = '70a149da27cc425da86cba890bf5b143'
       AND t5.type = "integration"
       AND t5.data.partnerAppId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY t4.uuid
LETTING m = MIN([t5.data.env, {t4.uuid, t4.data.appName, t4.data.description,
                    t5.data.env, t5.data.productStatus}]);
```